# How to get Current Fragment class instance from Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Activity1 placed with fragment and starting activity2 by action item after closing activity2 i need to get a fragment instance of current fragment placed in activity1? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not give enough details, but I will assume you have an activity with multiple fragments. Also let us assume you are using tabs for navigation.

To get an instance of a fragment you can make use of tags assigned to each fragment. Here is the function that returns the tag associated with a fragment:

```
 private static String makeFragmentName(int viewId, int position)
    {
         return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + position;
    }
```

And you would get the fragment like this:

```
   MyFragment fragment =  ((MyFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(makeFragmentName(R.id.pager,position)))
```

Where R.id.pager is the pager view containing the fragments (with tabs), and position is the position of the fragment in a tab layout.

Let me know how this works out for you.